# How to invoke IEDriver using Serenity

Tags: java, gradle, serenity-bdd

I know this is a basic question but I am just not able to solve it.

I downloaded the sample serenity project (mvn archetype serenity-junit-screenplay-archetype) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-6CcDFn5Ug) to search for "BDD in Action" in google.

I am using Gradle for my build compilation:

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.1.36")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

dependencies {
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.1.36'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.1.36'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:1.1.36'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:1.1.36'
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    compile('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0')
    compile('com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:2.3.3')
}
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

I have updated the "SearchByKeywordStory" as follows to include the "webdriver.driver" properties for IEDriver and ChromeDriver:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class SearchByKeywordStory {

    Actor anna = Actor.named("Anna");

    @Managed(uniqueSession = true, clearCookies=BeforeEachTest)
    public WebDriver herBrowser;

    @Steps
    OpenTheApplication openTheApplication;

    @Before
    public void annaCanBrowseTheWeb() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "../resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "../resources/chromedriver.exe");
        anna.can(BrowseTheWeb.with(herBrowser));
    }

    @Test
    public void search_results_should_show_the_search_term_in_the_title() {
        givenThat(anna).wasAbleTo(openTheApplication);

        when(anna).attemptsTo(Search.forTheTerm("BDD In Action"));

        then(anna).should(eventually(seeThat(TheWebPage.title(), containsString("BDD In Action"))));

    }
}
```

I use IntelliJ to execute my scenarios. The Chromedriver works flawlessly and the test passes. But the IEDriver does not work and when I run the test, I get the following error:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.48.0.0
Listening on port 35996

net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

```
at org.ao.automation.tasks.OpenTheApplication.performAs(OpenTheApplication.java:15)
at org.ao.automation.features.search.SearchByKeywordStory.search_results_should_show_the_search_term_in_the_title(SearchByKeywordStory.java:43)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

I have verified all the settings in IE (Protected Settings, Zoom level, registry value for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE)

I can see that the IE browser gets invoked (Starting Internet Explorer... blah) but it fails immediately after that.

I know for sure that the IEDriver works because I have several other Selenium maven projects with 100s of tests which have no problem invoking InternetExplorer.

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading the version of IE Driver to 2.53.0?